# Texture being rendered as black quad

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, opengl-3

I have been trying to follow the [code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.2.textures_combined/textures_combined.cpp) as specified in [this tutorial on OpenGL3+ textures](https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures), but my result ends up black instead of the texture.

[image]

I am using [stbimage](https://github.com/nothings/stb) to load the image the texture uses into a direct ByteBuffer and can guarantee the RGB data in the buffer is, at least, not uniform - so it can't be that.

I usually do not like to dump code, but I don't see much else I can do at this point. Here's my java code and shaders:

`GL` is an interface pointing to all the GL## functionality in LWJGL3<sup>1</sup>.

`ShaderProgram` wraps all the shader specific stuff into a nice blackbox that generates a shaderprogram from the attached shaders on the first call of `use(GL)` and subsequently reuses that program. This works just fine for rendering a coloured triangle, so I rule out any errors in there.

`Util.checkError(GL, boolean);` does check for any OpenGL errors that have accumulated since its last execution and throws a runtime exception if the boolean is not set (silently writes to the log instead, if set).

<sub>The rendering code, update(GL, long) is run once every frame</sub>

```
private static final ResourceAPI res = API.get(ResourceAPI.class);

Image lwjgl32;

ShaderProgram prog = new ShaderProgram();
int vbo, vao, ebo;
int texture;

@Override
public void init(GL gl) {

    try {
        prog.attach(res.get("shaders/texDemo.vert", ShaderSource.class));
        prog.attach(res.get("shaders/texDemo.frag", ShaderSource.class));
        lwjgl32 = res.get("textures/lwjgl32.png", Image.class);
    } catch(ResourceException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    float[] vertices = {
        // positions          // colors           // texture coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
    };

    int[] indices = {
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };

    vao = gl.glGenVertexArrays();
    vbo = gl.glGenBuffers();
    ebo = gl.glGenBuffers();

    gl.glBindVertexArray(vao);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * Float.BYTES, 0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * Float.BYTES, 3 * Float.BYTES);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * Float.BYTES, 6 * Float.BYTES);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    texture = gl.glGenTextures();
    gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);

    gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_REPEAT);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_REPEAT);

    gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGB8, lwjgl32.getWidth(), lwjgl32.getHeight(), 0, GL.GL_RGB, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, lwjgl32.getImageData());
    gl.glGenerateMipmap(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    prog.use(gl);
    gl.glUniform1i(gl.glGetUniformLocation(prog.getId(gl), "texture"), 0);

    Util.checkError(gl, false);
}

@Override
protected void update(GL gl, long deltaFrame) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    prog.use(gl);
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vao);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

@Override
public void clean(GL gl) {
    gl.glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);
    gl.glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
    gl.glDeleteBuffers(ebo);

    ShaderProgram.clearUse(gl);
    prog.dispose(gl);
}
```

<sub>Vertex shader</sub>

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 in_color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 in_texCoord;

out vec3 color;
out vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 1.0);

    color = in_color;
    texCoord = vec2(in_texCoord.x, in_texCoord.y);
}
```

<sub>Fragment shader</sub>

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 frag_colour;

in vec3 color;
in vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
    frag_colour = texture(texture, texCoord) * vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I wrapped LWJGL3's GL## static classes into a single interface and implementation so I can have a bunch of stateful methods that do things such as identifying the context that is being rendered to, etc. I also did my best to remove non-core functionality from the interface so I don't even get tempted to use deprecated stuff</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only enable the vertex attribute with index 0, but this 3 times.

Adapt your code like this:

```
gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * Float.BYTES, 0);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * Float.BYTES, 3 * Float.BYTES);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // <-------

gl.glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL.GL_FLOAT, false, 8 * Float.BYTES, 6 * Float.BYTES);
gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2); // <------
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from just looking at the code but a black quad means that this row in your fragment shader:

```
frag_colour = texture(texture, texCoord) * vec4(color, 1.0);
```

evaluates to 0. Which means either the texture is'nt read/bound properly, your texture coordinates are off or color is a zero vector. Make sure your texture image is properly loaded (file exists, has a width and height etc) and has the correct format. What I usually do to debug the shader is to set each parameter as a color to give a hint if it has the correct value:

```
frag_colour = vec4(color, 1.0); //Makes sure the color is right
```

or

```
frag_colour = texture(texture, texCoord); //Makes sure the texture is loaded and bound
```

And if that doesn't give enough information, even more detail:

```
frag_colour = vec4(color.x, color.x, color.x, 1.0);
```

or

```
frag_colour = vec4(texCoord.x, texCoord.x, texCoord.x, 1.0);
```